# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject() cannot parse Swagger response type that has a reference-typed property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, json.net, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a WebApi action which returns a strongly typed object having this class:

```
public class MyResponse
{
    public string Message { get; internal set; }
    public ChildObject ChildObject { get; internal set; }
}
```

Swashbuckle generates the JSON Swagger doc (edited for brevity):

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "version": "v1",
    "title": "empApi"
  },
  "host": "localhost:51299",
  "schemes": [
    "http"
  ],
  "paths": {
    "/api/v1/MyAction": {
      "post": {
        ...
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK",
            "schema": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/MyResponse"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    },
  "definitions": {
    "MyResponse": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "Message": {
          "type": "string",
          "readOnly": true
        },
        "ChildObject": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/ChildObject",
          "readOnly": true
        }
      }
    },
    "ChildObject": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This parsing code worked fine until I added ChildObject:

```
public static SwaggerDocument Parse(string src)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    var schemas = new SchemaResolver(); //Implements IReferenceResolver, maintains a Dictionary<string, Schema>
    settings.ReferenceResolverProvider = () => schemas;
    var swagger = JObject.Parse(src);
    var typesRoot = swagger.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == "definitions").FirstOrDefault();

    if (typesRoot != null)
    {
        foreach (var i in typesRoot.Values())
        {
            schemas.AddReference(null, "#/" + i.Path.Replace(".", "/"),
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Schema>((i as JProperty).Value.ToString(), settings));
        }
    }
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SwaggerDocument>(src, settings);
}
```

Exception:

> Additional content found in JSON reference object. A JSON reference object should only have a $ref property. Path 'properties.ChildObject.readOnly', line _, position _.
>       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadMetadataProperties(JsonReader reader, Type& objectType, JsonContract& contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue, Object& newValue, String& id)

**Is there a way to make JsonConvert handle this without making the setter public? (How do I ensure I can handle Swagger docs for WebApis I can't modify?)**

Comment: Can you share your entire project? Or maybe create a minimal one reproducing the issue?

Comment: Landed here for related issue serializing `SwaggerDocument` using `JsonConvert` and falling flat - [see this related GitHub issue](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/22#issuecomment-411115373).